# how to transform a dropdown list to a button with dropdown list popup

Tags: jquery, html

I need to modify a dropdown list:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/now.png

to this widget (not sure how to define it):
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/later.png

I can use jQuery for it.. or maybe there is a html form element ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved in a very very simple way:

I just removed the attribute size from html code:

```
<select size="5">
```

to

```
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [this jquery plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) allowing you to customize the look and feel of the default dropdown boxes.

Comment: uhm, it looks great, but I need to download jQueryUI and jQueryUI Theme as well, in order to use it. I was wondering if there is a simpler solution for this small change.